# Juntar um número de pessoas sem repetir a combinação com o máximo estipulado

Tags: php, lógica

Eu tenho `N pessoas` para formar tantas reuniões possíveis. Essas `N pessoas` não podem falar com quem já falaram em outras reuniões. Cada reunião tem no máximo `N pessoas`.

Baseado nessas informações eu consigo montar um exemplo:

```
$pessoasIds = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...120); // Até 120 pessoas
$maxPessoas = 13; // 13 pessoas por reunião
```

Tem alguns pontos chaves que devem ser considerados:

- Não posso permitir que a `Pessoa 1` fale com a `Pessoa 2` se elas ja conversaram em qualquer outra reunião. Vou dar um exemplo utilizando `6 pessoas` com no máximo de `3 por reunião` Um exemplo seria esse:

```
    $reunioes = array(
        0 => array(1, 2, 3),
        1 => array(1, 4, 5),
        2 => array(1, 6),
        3 => array(2, 4, 6), // a pessoa número 2 ja conversou com a pessoa número 3 e 1 e a pessoa número 4 com a 5
        4 => array(2, 5) 
    );
```

- Preciso manter o número máximo de pessoas por reunião e não posso ultrapassar este valor.
- Preciso manter no mínimo uma reunião por pessoa. Mas preciso também, fazer com que cada pessoa tenha um número parecido de reuniões, para não ficar muito desigual. Claro que terá pessoas com menos reuniões que as outras, mas desde que essa diferença seja pequena tudo bem.
- Além de manter o número máximo de pessoas em cada reunião, preciso também tentar manter um número padrão de pessoas. Por exemplo, preciso que pelo menos que a maioria das pessoas consiga fazer uma reunião e que seja com 13 pessoas cada. Se as outras reuniões forem de 8, 7, 5 ou 2 pessoas nao tem problema, mas que pelo menos uma boa parte das reuniões tenha o número igual de participantes, de novo para não ser injusto.
- Preciso manter também uma certa ordem de combinação. Ao trazer todas as pessoas do banco de dados, preciso ordená-las pela ordem de prioridade. A prioridade mais alta vem primeiro, com mais chance de ter reuniões agendadas.

Agora, tentei algumas lógicas diferentes mas nenhuma deu certo:

### Primeira Tentativa

Pegar a `Pessoa 1` e ir combinando com todas as outras, até formar 13 reunioes por pessoa. O problema é que a `Pessoa 1` vai ter sempre mais reuniões que as outras, porque como é a primeira, não existe ainda nenhuma reunião, ninguém conversou com ninguém ainda.

### Segunda Tentativa

Tentei combinar apenas `uma` reunião de cada pessoa e voltar para a primeira. Por exemplo: monto a combinação da reunião da `Pessoa 1`. Passo para a segunda pessoa, terceira e assim até a ultima. Quando chegar na última, volta para a primeira pessoa e vejo se ainda é possível gerar outra reunião. Não deu certo também pois o número de pessoas em cada reunião ficou muito desigual. Exemplo: Em uma lista de 120 pessoas com 13 pessoas em cada reunião, lá pela 11º reunião estava se formando já apenas duas pessoas por reunião.

### Terceira Tentativa

Essa tentativa teve base em combinar de um em um. Pego a primeira pessoa e adiciono outra, formando assim uma reunião de duas pessoas. Faço o mesmo com a segunda pessoa, terceira e assim por diante até chegar no máximo de pessoas por reunião em cada uma. O problema dessa tentativa eu mostro logo abaixo, que vou colocar como exemplo em PHP:

```
$reunioes = array(
    1 => array(1,2), // reunião da pessoa número 1
    2 => array(2,3), // reunião da pessoa número 2 e etc...
    3 => array(3,1)
    4 => array(4,1),
    5 => array(5,1)
    // ...
);
```

Quando eu tentar gerar a próxima leva de reuniões para `Pessoa 1` novamente, ela não vai ter mais nenhuma reunião a ser gerada, porque todo mundo já falou com a `Pessoa 1`.

### Objetivo

O objetivo final é formar reuniões com a média de pessoas parecida em cada grupo, respeitando todas as 'regras' que escrevi na pergunta

Pode acontecer de ter reuniões de duas pessoas, mas a preferência é que sempre tente alcançar o máximo de pessoas em uma reunião, que no exemplo que eu dei é 13. Se o limite dado for 5 pessoas por reunião, o ideal seria que todas as reuniões fossem com 5 pessoas, mas isso depende de quantas pessoas tem e etc, então é normal que algumas tenham menos que as outras e aceitável!

### Outros detalhes

Notar também que eu irei utilizar ID's e não números sequênciais. Ao inves de usar `1,2,3,4`, vou estar utilizando `46,12,13,10,1,9` que seriam os ID's de cada pessoa.

Comment: Sim, estou utilizando.

Comment: Não entendi o objetivo final. Seria formar grupos(reuniões) de pessoas com uma média de quantidade parecida em cada grupo, obedecendo as considerações que você citou?

Comment: Exatamente @Earendul. O objetivo final é formar reuniões com a média de pessoas parecida em cada grupo, respeitando todas as 'regras' que escrevi na pergunta.

Comment: As reuniões devem ser sempre com 13 pessoas? ou podemos ter reuniões de 2 pessoas?

Comment: Pode ter reuniões de duas pessoas sim, mas a preferência é que sempre tente alcançar o máximo de pessoas em uma reunião, que no exemplo que eu dei é 13. Se o limite dado for 5 pessoas por reunião, o ideal seria que todas as reuniões fossem com 5 pessoas, mas isso depende de quantas pessoas tem e etc, então é normal que algumas tenham menos que as outras e aceitável!

Comment: Primeiro pegue o número de pessoas e divide pelo máximo:
EX 50 pessoas em 5 da 10, logo conseguiremos fazer 10 reuniões, sem que ninguém esteve presente em duas.

EX(grupos chave): 1-5, 6-10, 11-15 16-20, 21-25 26-30, 31-35 36-40, 41-45 46-50

depois disso pegue uma pessoa de cada grupo chave (logo teremos mais 10 reuniões)

1-6-11-16-21
26-31-36-41-46
2-7-12-17-22
etc

Comment: faça a mesma coisa com os grupos chave de 6 a 10 6-1 7-2...

seguindo a mesma analogia, supondo que você numere os integrantes dos grupos chaves de 1 à 5 para os 5 primeiros e de 6-10 para os últimos, 

após estabelecer os chaves é só trabalhar da seguinte forma:(para facilitar utilizarei x=10.


esquema de vizualização 

exemplo grupo chave 4 = 16 17 18 19 20 
onde 16=1 17=2 18=3 19=4 e 20=5

na numerologia 12345 é primeira pessoa do grupo chave 1, a seg do 2, a 3 do 3, a 4 do 4, e a 5 do 5
se fosse 23456 seria:
a segunda pessoa do grupo1, 3 do 2 a 4 do 3 a 5 do 4 e a primeira do 6

Comment: - grupo dos ordenados

11111 22222 33333 44444 55555 66666 77777 88888 99999 xxxxx

 - grupo dos sequenciais com 1 como base

12345 13456 14567 15678 16789 1789x 189x2 19x23 1x2345 logo o 1 do primeiro grupo ja participou de todas as reuniões dele

 - repetir os grupos anteriores agora usando 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,x como base:

21354 23547 25476 24769 27698 2698x 298x1 

e seguir a mesma analogia 

ou seja forme arranjos para os seus grupos, sem repetição.

Comment: @Joannis Poderias colocar isto como resposta, ;)

Comment: Concordo. Utilizei seu método e deu certo. @Joannis, você poderia colocar como resposta para eu marcar como resolvido?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro pegue o número de pessoas e divide pelo máximo:

EX 50 pessoas em 5 da 10, logo conseguiremos fazer 10 reuniões, sem que ninguém esteve presente em duas.

EX(grupos chave): 1-5, 6-10, 11-15 16-20, 21-25 26-30, 31-35 36-40, 41-45 46-50 depois disso pegue uma pessoa de cada grupo chave (logo teremos mais 10 reuniões) 1-6-11-16-21 26-31-36-41-46 2-7-12-17-22 etc

faça a mesma coisa com os grupos chave de 6 a 10 6-1 7-2... seguindo a mesma analogia, supondo que você numere os integrantes dos grupos chaves de 1 à 5 para os 5 primeiros e de 6-10 para os últimos, após estabelecer os chaves é só trabalhar da seguinte forma:

(para facilitar utilizarei x=10).

esquema de visualização exemplo grupo chave 4 = 16 17 18 19 20 onde 16=1 17=2 18=3 19=4 e 20=5 na numerologia 12345 é primeira pessoa do grupo chave 1, a seg do 2, a 3 do 3, a 4 do 4, e a 5 do 5 se fosse 23456 seria: a segunda pessoa do grupo1, 3 do 2 a 4 do 3 a 5 do 4 e a primeira do 6

grupo dos ordenados

11111 22222 33333 44444 55555 66666 77777 88888 99999 xxxxx -

grupo dos sequenciais com 1 como base

12345 13456 14567 15678 16789 1789x 189x2 19x23 1x2345 logo o 1 do primeiro grupo ja participou de todas as reuniões dele - repetir os grupos anteriores agora usando 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,x como base:

21354 23547 25476 24769 27698 2698x 298x1

e seguir a mesma analogia ou seja forme arranjos para os seus grupos, sem repetição

Answer (score 1):

Fiz alguma coisa semelhante, mas para pegar somente as pessoas disponíveis sem que elas tenham que se confrontar na mesma vaga, espero que te ajude:

http://ideone.com/KNYZYU